# DescribeFieldResult.getSOAPType() returns type not in enum list

Tags: apex, soap-api, describesobject, describefieldresult, sobjecttype

Was working on some generic apex, and wrote a few lines of code to get the `SOAPType` of a field based on the type and the name. Went off, and worked on some other areas, and wrote something which used that code on a `BillingAddress`. I expected it to fail, but it provided to the correct type: `ADDRESS`.

Here's a snippet to replicate:

```
SObjectType internalDescribeType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Schema.SObjectField fieldDescribe = internalDescribeType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('BillingAddress');

System.debug(fieldDescribe.getDescribe().getSOAPType());
```

The debug output for this snippet will result in:

> 13:08:59:111 USER_DEBUG [33]|DEBUG|ADDRESS

But, neither the [SOAPType enum](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_SOAPType.htm) or the [DisplayType enum](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm) support this value. Is this intended undocumented behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a very large number of `SoapType` values which are not contained in your linked document. When I investigated, I found 619.

```
system.debug(SoapType.values().size()); // yields 619
for (SoapType st : SoapType.values()) system.debug(st);
```

If you look through the logs, you will indeed see `ADDRESS` listed:

> 12:11:07:006 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|LOCATION
>   12:11:07:006 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|ADDRESS
>   12:11:07:006 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|MAP_ENTRY

Can't say I know what even half of them mean, but I can at least verify `ADDRESS` is a valid `Enum` value for `SoapType`.

Comment: I also get 619 types when running that snippet, and of those types, 25 can be used with `Type.forName(...)`, and 15 of those can be used with `Type.newInstance()`. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the documentation for SOAPType and refer to your WSDL to see what each field will return. All fields should return a type.

You may also want to check the documentation for [SOAPType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#soaptype_topic) and [FieldTypes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm#i1435616)

So if you look at BillingAddress in the WSDL you will get the TNS type ADDRESS as the return.

```
<element name="BillingAddress" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:address"/>
```

Also a little more testing, it is just `tns:address`, `tns:ID` and `tns:anytype` fields that I've found to return values. Others in the Field Types list might not, so I would suggest testing on your org.

Comment: The point of this question is that some of these `SOAPType` exist, but are not in the documentation. What is interesting, and I would have failed to notice this if not for your answer, is that the `<simpleType name="soapType">` tag has the values from the documentation, as well as `address` and `location`, plus some other `urn` values.

Comment: @battery.cord The documentation isn't necessarily authorative. For example, I once enumerated every object type by Id hack and found a ton of things that are not in a document anywhere.